# RabbitMQ 2 listener on 1 queue do one work (1st and 2nd listener do it)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I need help:  How to make sure that the events of the one queue are necessarily processed by 2 listeners (and 1 and 2). Is it possible ? Example: my data is stored in 2 databases in different services, when I create a queue event, I need both services to delete information in their databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; RabbitMQ doesn't work that way; each consumer needs its own queue; bind two queues to the exchange and make sure both get all messages either by binding with the same routing key or by using a Fanout exchange.

See the tutorials https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html